# How to handle splash screen stretched issue in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am developing an Android application which will work for all resolution devices. For all resolutions like 320*480, 480*800, 720*1280 devices i used different splash screen image and places screen image in mdpi(320*480), hdpi(480*800), xhdpi(720*1280) drawable folders. Here I am facing problem with 540*960 devices. Those also comes under hdpi resolution.So image getting from hdpi folder and showing stretched and blurred. Please advice me how to distribute proper image for 540*960 devices. Here I have some another background image for 540*960 those are different from hdpi devices resolution.

Please how can I give proper image for 540*960 devices.

Comment: you can create a separate hdpi folder for those devices something like this `drawable-hdpi-960x540` but you should go with  @Android user's answer

Comment: I tried drawable folder with drawable-hdpi-960x540 not not getting images from this folder